# File locking with CTDB and GlusterFS not working

Tags: samba, cluster, glusterfs

We are having issues getting our GlusterFS and CTDB implementation to work. It could be that what we are attempting to do is not supported but I'm not able to understand why.

We have two file servers that are connected over a permanent VPN link. On either side of the link we want the clients in their corresponding LANs to only have to access their local file-server. GlusterFS takes care of the replication between the two over the slow VPN link. We had *hoped* that CTDB would update and replicate the TDB database quickly so even though the link is slow (for file transfers) we could at least grab locks fairly quickly.

The problem is that it doesn't work. We set everything up following:

[GlusterFS QuickStart](http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/QuickStart)

and
[CTDB Quickstart](https://ctdb.samba.org/samba.html)

And file locking from windows clients doesn't work, out of the box.

What *does* work is if we have all clients connect to the same Samba share. Problem is that if we do that we have one office going over the slow VPN link, which is what we are trying to eliminate.

File replication works all the time. So I imagine this is either us trying to implement something incorrectly or our use-case is no good for CTDB.

Comment: When you said "file lock from Windows clients doesn't work," what led you to this conclusion? I just set up ctdb on glusterfs and initially I had a problem with the glusterfs portion where samba (before ctdb was introduced) was hanging for a long time before timing out and continuing. Upon inspecting log entries, we found hint to issues with byte-range locking issue. So we disabled byte-range locking (using "posix locking = no" after reviewing several locking options). I am wondering if this is what you are encountering.

Comment: So what I wrote was probably too vague. It's actually a problem with Microsoft Office and applications that don't use POSIX locks. If I have a word document open on a Windows 7 machine and try to open the same file from a OS X machine or a Linux machine there is no lock warning. Also sometimes the lock doesn't work between Windows machines as its too slow to write and propagate the hidden "lock file" that Office creates when you open a document.

Comment: Are the OS X and Linux machines also connecting to the storage via SMB? The lock warnings will only work in this case...

Comment: Could you detail more about your setup? For a ctdb setup, it is important that all nodes belong to the same samba/ctdb cluster. I.e. your nodes need to have the same samba configuration and be configured with "clustering = yes". Ideally, I'd need to see your samba and ctdb configs to tell if your setup is expected to work.